# Returning time portion only for formik timepicker

Tags: reactjs, datetime, formik, formik-material-ui

I am using Formik TimePicker as all I require is just the time selection from the user, including seconds, i.e. `format="HH:mm:ss"`

The issue I am facing is that when I view the final result, I've noticed that it's also returning the date as well and prepends this to the time.

I have example code here: [CodeSandbox-timepicker](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-time-picker-orjh7?file=/src/index.tsx:1044-1061)

As you can see, when you select a time and press the "Submit" button, you will see that date with the time.

Is there any means of just returning the time portion only - `format="HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: I can't see any option for that in the documentation, so you'll just have to format it manually. This is pretty easy to do with a regex replace, just do `time = time.split(/T(.*)\./g)[1];`

Answer (score 0):

You need to format date and there are number of libraries which can help in formatting dates. Here I am using `format` from [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)

So just format date by following:-

```
import {format} from 'date-fns'; // import statement

...
...

format(values.time, 'HH:mm:ss') // format date with desired format
```

Working demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-time-picker-ixxxp

Comment: Is there any means of being able to perform this formatting as part of the onChange event within the `<TimePicker>` component?

Comment: TimePicker component will always return combination of date and time so I think we always have to format date on our side.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the time from the datetime without using any external libraries by converting the string to a `Date` object and using `toLocaleTime`.

```js
const time  = new Date(values.time).toLocaleTimeString();
alert(time);
```